# getting average in java with difference of values

Tags: java, computer-science

So I just need some help with getting the correct average for my program. It is not accurate because it is sum/ the total count but I need to just have it be divided by the two lowest values, min and max. Here is the necessary portion of my code for reference.

```
int count = 0;
        int totalVal;

        while (input.hasNext()) {

            String tdate = input.next();
            String ttime = input.next();
            int tdata = input.nextInt();
            count++;

            if (tdata <= smallest) {
                smallest = tdata;
                minDate=tdate;
                minTime=ttime; 
            }

            if (tdata >= largest) {
                largest = tdata;
                maxDate=tdate; 
                maxTime=ttime; 


            }

        }

        double sum = smallest + largest;
        double average = sum / count;

        System.out.println("\n" + count); 
        System.out.println("Minimum: " + smallest + "@" +  minDate +" " + minTime);
        System.out.println("Maximum " + largest  + "@" + maxDate +" " + maxTime); 
        System.out.println("%.2d" + average);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I just need some help with getting the correct average for my program. It is not accurate because it is sum/ the total count but I need to just have it be divided by the two lowest values, min and max.

1 "correct average" typically means `sum / number_of_elements`

2 "I need to just have it be divided by the two lowest values, min and max." the minimum and maximum of the two lowest values? Or the minimum and maximum of all the values?

I'll assume you need to divide the sum by the minimum and maximum of all the values. You need to calculate the actual sum and divide it by `smallest + largest`, not set `sum = smallest + largest`. Example:

```
int count = 0;
int totalVal = 0; // don't need this variable
double sum = 0.0;

while (input.hasNext()) {
    String tdate = input.next();
    String ttime = input.next();
    int tdata = input.nextInt();
    sum += tdata;
    count++;

    if (tdata <= smallest) {
        smallest = tdata;
        minDate=tdate;
        minTime=ttime; 
    }

    if (tdata >= largest) {
        largest = tdata;
        maxDate=tdate; 
        maxTime=ttime; 
    }

}

double average = sum / (double) (smallest + largest);

// the rest of your code
```

Comment: that just outputted 0.0 as the average

Comment: I changed to `double average = sum / (double) (smallest + largest);` and added the `sum += tdata;` but it is not calculating the average correctly, I got an average of `4.47` while it should be `57.5`. Since 57 + 58/ 2= 57.5.

Comment: @javakook 57 is the lowest, 58 is the largest, 2 is the total count, 57 + 58 is the sum... your question states "It is not accurate because it is **sum/ the total count** but I need to just have it be **divided by the two lowest values, min and max**" ... my example does the latter, it divides the sum by the minimum and the maximum.

Comment: Sorry I did word that poorly, so my question is how can I get the average to print as 57.5.

Comment: @javakook I think your looking for `double sum = smallest + largest; double average = sum / 2;`

Comment: I just realized how obvious that was, thanks. How do I get the average to print out to the hundredths place, this is what I did but it didn't work, `System.out.printd("%02d" + average);`

Comment: @javakook correction: `System.out.printf("%.2f", average);` will work.

Comment: The time and data output I'm getting is somehow off, what can that be? Ex: it should be Minimum: `57 @ 2013-08-20 01:10:01` but it is   `57 @ 2013-08-20 01:50:02`